# Como utilizar o Algoritmo de Verificação de Ciclo em Grafos?

Tags: algoritmo, grafo

Olá, gostaria de saber como utilizar o Algoritmo de Verificação de Ciclo em Grafos para encontrar uma condição cíclica, se puder me colocar a utilização do algoritmo neste Grafo abaixo:

[image: grafo]

Comment: Você fala de grafos dirigidos?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546655/finding-all-cycles-in-a-directed-graph

Answer (score 5):

Existem vários algoritmos que podem ser usados para identificar ciclos em grafos. O mais simples é a busca em produndidade (DFS na sigla em inglês). Basta implementar uma busca em profundidade que retorna `true` caso encontre um nodo já visitado.

Uma limitação deste algoritmo é a performance. Como o DFS precisa de um nodo raiz, é necessário rodar o DFS pra cada nodo presente no grafo.

Segue uma implementação que eu escrevi em Python:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

class Grafo():
    def __init__(self):
        self._data = defaultdict(list)

    def conectar(self, nodo_origem, nodo_destino):
        self._data[nodo_origem].append(nodo_destino)

    def vizinhos(self, nodo):
        return self._data[nodo]

    def verificar_ciclos(self, nodo_inicial):
        nodos_visitados = set()
        nodos_restantes = [nodo_inicial]

        while nodos_restantes:
            nodo_atual = nodos_restantes.pop()
            nodos_visitados.add(nodo_atual)

            for vizinho in self.vizinhos(nodo_atual):
                if vizinho in nodos_visitados:
                    return True

                nodos_restantes.append(vizinho)

        return False
```

Essa classe detecta corretamente o ciclo do grafo exibido na pergunta:

```py
grafo = Grafo()

grafo.conectar('A', 'R2')
grafo.conectar('R2', 'B')
grafo.conectar('B', 'R1')
grafo.conectar('R1', 'A')

if grafo.verificar_ciclos('A'):
    print('Encontrou um ciclo')
else:
    print('Não encontrou ciclo')
```

Há outros algoritmos mais sofisticados, mas o DFS resolve o problema e é um bom começo pra quem está estudando grafos.

Answer (score -5):

```py
   from collections import defaultdict
   class Grafo():
       def __init__(self):
           self._data = defaultdict(list)
   
       def conectar(self, nodo_origem, nodo_destino):
           self._data[nodo_origem].append(nodo_destino)
   
       def vizinhos(self, nodo):
           return self._data[nodo]
   
       def verificar_ciclos(self, nodo_inicial):
           nodos_visitados = set()
           nodos_restantes = [nodo_inicial]
   
           while nodos_restantes:
               nodo_atual = nodos_restantes.pop()
               nodos_visitados.add(nodo_atual)
   
               for vizinho in self.vizinhos(nodo_atual):
                   if vizinho in nodos_visitados:
                       return True
   
                   nodos_restantes.append(vizinho)
   
           return False
   
   grafo = Grafo()
    
nodos = ['2','3','5','7','8','9','10','11']
   
   grafo.conectar('7','11')
   grafo.conectar('7','8')
   grafo.conectar('5','11')
   grafo.conectar('3','8')
   grafo.conectar('3','10')
   grafo.conectar('11','2')
   grafo.conectar('11','9')
   grafo.conectar('11','10')
   grafo.conectar('8','9')
   
   for i in range(len(nodos)): 
       if grafo.verificar_ciclos(nodos[i]):
           print('Existe Cilo no Vertice: ',nodos[i])
       else:
           print('Sem Ciclos para: ',nodos[i])
```

Fiz este teste usando sua resposta para um gráfico sem Ciclos, e ele retornou que existia um Ciclo, o 7, mas não é para existir:
Errei alguma coisa?

```
Sem Ciclos para:  2
Sem Ciclos para:  3
Sem Ciclos para:  5
Existe Cilo no Vertice:  7
Sem Ciclos para:  8
Sem Ciclos para:  9
Sem Ciclos para:  10
Sem Ciclos para:  11
```

Comment: Isto não responde à pergunta... Quando tiver 50 pontos de reputação, poderá deixar comentários em outras publicações.